# HTTPS links not recognized as valid URLS

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, ssl

When trying to vote to close a question as a duplicate, I copied the link to the duplicate question and, as I use HTTPS by default, the link was rejected with an error message along the lines of "not a valid URL".

Removing the `s` and just using `http://...` and the appropriate question was highlighted, allowing me to cast my vote.

Surely, we should be able to access all of the functionality over a secure connection?

Related feature request on the main meta: [Better HTTPS support for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: HTTPS is not officially supported yet, so it's to be expected that some things still break.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles: I was reporting it as much to let them know where the breakage was. Otherwise, even if not officially supported, it is working pretty well...